# Analyze format of pdf-file and extract text and images

Tags: pdf, text-extraction

I need to extract the "articles" from this magazine which has both text and images. The image content has to be placed separately, the text extracted (as far as possible) and placed separately.

How do i go about doing this? Is there a commercial service / api that does this already? The input to the program/service will just be the file.

Eg of input: http://edition.pagesuite-professional.co.uk/pdfspool/rQBvRbttuPUWUoJlU6dBVSRnIlE=.pdf

(the actual file would be a normal pdf-file, not a seured one)

Answer (score 1):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can extract images and text from PDF files for you.

Here are couple of samples for your task:

- [Extract text from PDFs](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract)
- [Extract images from a PDF](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Images/ExtractImages)

Extracted images can be saved as JPEG and TIFFs. You can extract text from each page or from the whole document. And you can extract text chunks with their coordinates.

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle, vendor of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

http://asp.syncfusion.com/sfaspnetsamplebrowser/9.1.0.20/Web/Pdf.Web/samples/4.0/Importing/TextExtraction/CS/Default.aspx?args=7

The same component has the image-extraction feature also.

You could make a try!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford a commercial option, [Amyuni PDF Creator](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html) will allow you to enumerate all components inside the pdf file (text, image, etc), you will be able to extract them as independent objects and you can create new PDF files with them.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies.

Comment: that's interesting to know - can we break the pdf into its consitutent elements - eg: a page may have two articles and two related images (typically, they'll have much more)

Comment: are you sure i can use your tool to extract?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you may need to know the rectangular region you want to extract from beforehand, it depends on the specific files you have. The tool will not be able to tell you if an image is related to a portion of text for example. You can use the evaluation version and try it with your files, and you can also get support during the evalution period. You can either use the .net  version (for C#, vb.net etc) or the ActiveX version (C++, Delphi, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Aspose.Pdf.Kit](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/default.aspx) to [extract text and images separately from a PDF file](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/working-with-features-of-pdfextractor-class.html). The API is quite simple. You can also find samples, tutorials and support on Aspose website.

*Note: I'm working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.*